# Node.js, Mongo find last 10 items sort by start date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This time I have problem with querying last X records with certain value from mongodb.

What I have so far ->

```
Data.find({'ResourceID': 61}, {}, {limit: 10}, function (err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
```

This returns first 10 records. How can I get last 10?

---

EDIT :

This works, but can I convert this to the looks of the upper or whats the point of this 'exec' function?->

```
Data.find({
        'ResourceID': 61
    }).sort('-Start').limit(10).exec(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
 });
```

Comment: Data.find({'ResourceID': 61}, {'Start':-1}, {limit: 10}, function (err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});

Comment: Only returns Start from every record. I need all keys and values